# CVE-2017-10661 triggering

Tags: android, security, linux-kernel

I'm trying to make a c program which triggers [CVE-2017-10661](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-10661).

As far as I understand because might_cancel mechanism it isn't properly protected if you make parallel operations on the file descriptor you can cause a crash.

I believe these parallel operations are read, poll etc right?

Currently i have written this piece of code.

```
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int timerfd;
    int epollfd;
    struct itimerspec timerValue;
    uint64_t exp;
    ssize_t s;

/* set timerfd */
timerfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
if (timerfd < 0) {
    printf("failed to create timer fd\n");
    exit(1);
}
bzero(&timerValue, sizeof(timerValue));
timerValue.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
timerValue.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
timerValue.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
timerValue.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

/* start timer */
if (timerfd_settime(timerfd, 0, &timerValue, NULL) < 0) {
    printf("could not start timer\n");
    exit(1);
}
    s = read( timerfd, &exp, sizeof(uint64_t));
    exit(0);
}
```

As you can see i set up a timer and then i only do a reading operation. Is there any way t trigger the bug by doing mupltiple read or pollings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The race condition is triggered by `timerfd_settime()` -> `timerfd_setup_cancel()` -> `timerfd_setup_cancel()`. So you should use multiple threads to do `timerfd_settime` with the flag as `TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME|TFD_TIMER_CANCEL_ON_SET`.

Here is the [POC](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dvyukov/202576d437c84ffbbe52e9ccd77e1b44/raw/5562bff8626a73627157331ea2b837f59080ac84/gistfile1.txt) I found online.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful! I was using multiple threads but with `read`. I'll try it right now

Comment: So, should this POC trigger the bug?

Comment: Yes, it should. The bug is found by this POC which is autogen by syzkaller.